# Adding Angular material and consuming in workspace throws inject error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-workspace-configuration

I started with  Angular Workspace,

```
1. Project 1
2. Project 2
3. SharedLib //The sharedlibrary
```

in `Project1` and `Project2`, I imported the `sharedLib`.

In SharedLib, I created a component with `Material Button Component`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HelloComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     CommonModule,
     MatButtonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HelloComponentComponent
  ]
})
export class SamplesharedlibraryModule { }
```

HelloComponent.html

```html
 

<button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

Now getting this error

> Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

Comment: Where are you using the `inject` function? within the HelloComponent? Share that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the setting in tsconfig.
The dependencies of shared libraries should be added as a path in the tsconfig of the consuming application. In your case either Project1 or Project2.

like this,

```
{
  "paths": {
    "@angular/*": [
      "../.././node_modules/@angular/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

also you should have separate tsconfig file for shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks, adding the path in json, worked !!